# No method declared with Objective-C selector ('nextPage')

Tags: ios, swift

xcode creates some warnings since I updated to 7.3.1: "No method declared with Objective-C selector ('nextPage')". I'm not sure what I need to do now. These are the two lines that produce the warning:

```
let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer (target: self, action: Selector("nextPage"))
let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer (target: self, action: Selector("nextPage"))
```

This is the entire VC code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class VC1 : UIViewController {

class MyCustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

        return (visibleViewController?.supportedInterfaceOrientations())!

    }


    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {

        return (visibleViewController?.shouldAutorotate())!

    }

}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait

}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {

    return true

}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    func nextPage(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        switch sender.direction {



        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:

            print("SWIPED LEFT", terminator: "")

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("seg1", sender: nil)

        default:

            break

        }


    let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer (target: self, action: Selector("nextPage"))

    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer (target: self, action: Selector("nextPage"))


    leftSwipe.direction = .Left

    rightSwipe.direction = .Right



    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)

    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

}

    }

}
```

I found this when researching:

**Selector("funcName") was changed to #selector(ClassName.funcName)**

I imagine that "funcName" would be nextPage, but what do I have to set as ClassName?

Unfortunately, xcode doesn't provide any suggestions to fix this. Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: Your function nextPage is inside viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `nextPage` out of `viewDidLoad()` and then `#selector(VC1.nextPage)`

```
func nextPage(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    switch sender.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:

        print("SWIPED LEFT", terminator: "")

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("seg1", sender: nil)

       default:

        break

    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

   super.viewDidLoad()

   let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer (target: self, action:  #selector(VC1.nextPage))

   let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer (target: self, action:  #selector(VC1.nextPage))
}
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks! What about the last four lines of code? Do I keep them?

leftSwipe.direction = .Left
rightSwipe.direction = .Right
        
view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

Comment: I deleted some of the }} after exchanging the code. It works now. Thank you!